# D3.js and jQuery - multiple map points and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I'm new at D3.js and I've been asked to take over a project that someone else at work started.

The goal is to have a map that pulls in json data for the points, and then when the points are clicked, a jQuery dialog popups with the correct json data for each point.

I've been able to get the jQuery popup to work on the map, but every point that is clicked is populating with the exact same text.

I've also tested loading and displaying the json data in a simple html page using $.getJSON, and I was able to get that to loop through all of the json data just fine.

Below is the function that creates the points:

```
function addCirclesForArray(element,index,array) {
  var coordinates = 
  projection([element.sendLocation.longitude,element.sendLocation.latitude]);
    g.append("circle")
     .attr("cx",coordinates[0])
     .attr("cy",coordinates[1])
     .attr("r",(index<array.length-1)?2:4)
     .attr("r",4)
     .style("fill",$colorScale(d3.round(element.profileReadings[0].psal))) 
     .attr("class","circle")
     g.selectAll("circle")
    .on("click",circleClicked) 
}
```

And here is my method for looping through the json data for the jQuery popups:

```
function circleClicked(data, i) {       
    console.log(data) // undefined
    console.log(i); // index #
    $.getJSON("data/oc-readings3.json", function(data){ 
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
          //populate jQuery dialog
          $('#floatID').text("Float ID: "+value.platformNumber);
          $('#latitude').text("Latitude: "+value.sendLocation.latitude);
          $('#longitude').text("Longitude: "+value.sendLocation.longitude);

          // jQuery UI dialog and tabs
          $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ width: 400 })     

        });                 
    });                 
}
```

I'm probably missing something simple with the loop in the getJSON method, or maybe it has to do with data being undefined. If you have any tips, please let me know. Thanks.

**UPDATE/Solution**
I realized that I didn't need to use $.getJSON since I was already getting the json data in the addCirclesForArray method. I could just use the index from the passed in array parameter.

I also got rid of the circleClicked method and added the new logic to the addCirclesForArray method.

```
g.selectAll("circle")   
  .on("mouseover", increaseSize)
  .on("mouseout", decreaseSize)  
  .on("click", function(d,i) {
   //console.log(array[i]); 
     //jQuery popup
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
        width: 418,
        resizable: false
      });        
     //populate tabs
     $('#floatID').text("Float ID: "+array[i].platformNumber);
     // etc.
```

Comment: Where are you binding the data to the circles?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm only binding the data to the html for the jQuery dialog, not the circles. Maybe that's my issue?

Comment: I would think so since you are calling the click event from the context of the circles but there is no data bound to them...reason for the undefined data at the beginning of the listener.

Comment: But I would strongly suggest you generate a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/) for your example...I am not totally clear on how you are putting things together.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind a (*click*, *mouseover*, etc) handler using d3's *selection.on(type, callback)*, your callback function is called with its context ("this") bound to the DOM node which was clicked, and the element's data as its first parameter.
In order for this to work, you need to first bind data to your D3-created DOM/SVG nodes.

I recommend using declarative data binding instead of looping through the data elements. D3's creator, Mike Bostock, provides [a general overview on declarative binding in d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) ("joins"), as well as a [thorough, technical explanation](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/).

As for the dialog, the basic idea is to define only one dialog/popup/tooltip, which is hidden initially and reused for every node that is clicked. From the callback function, you can replace placeholder fields in your dialog with the actual values from your data object.

Your example could probably be modified to look like this:

```
var containerElement = $('#container'),
    svg = d3.select(containerElement).append('svg')
             /* .attr('width', ...).attr('height',...)*/;

// jQuery UI dialog and tabs
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ width: 400 });

$.getJSON("data/oc-readings3.json", addCirclesForArray); 

/** called only once */
function addCirclesForArray(data) {
  var coordinates = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
        coordinates.push(projection([value.sendLocation.longitude, value.sendLocation.latitude]));
  });

  // data join / declarative binding
  // caution: binding requires an array of array(s)!
  var groups = svg.selectAll('g').data([data]); 

  // exit
  groups.exit().remove();

  // enter
  groups.enter().append("svg:circle");

  // enter + update
  groups.attr("cx",coordinates[0])
      .attr("cy",coordinates[1])
      .attr("r", function(d,index) { 
          return (index<array.length-1)? 2: 4;
      })
      //.attr("r", 4) // duplicate assignment of r
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
          return $colorScale(d3.round(d.profileReadings[0].psal));
      }) 
      .attr("class","circle");
  groups.selectAll("circle")
      .on("click", circleClicked); // :TODO: bind circleClicked to your preferred context
}

/**
 * @param {arrayElement} data
 * @this {svg:circle} 
 */
function circleClicked(data) {
   var dialog = $('dialogPlaceholder');
   $('#floatID', dialog).text("Float ID: " + data.platformNumber);
   $('#latitude', dialog).text("Latitude: " + data.sendLocation.latitude);
   $('#longitude', dialog).text("Longitude: " + data.sendLocation.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code rewrite, explanations and links. The map isn't populating with the points now and the popups aren't working correctly, so I'll work on a complete plunk as FernOfTheAndes suggested, since you guys were only seeing part of my code.